# Django Model.objects.all() does not show in suggestions

Tags: python, django, models

I am using Python Tools for Visual Studio (Python 3 and django 1.6) and trying to access data from a table like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template, Context
from ticket.models import Task

def ticket_listing(request):
   objects = Task.objects.all().order_by('-due_date')
   template = Template('{%for elem in objects %} {{elem}}<br/> {% endfor %}')
   context = Context({'objects', objects})
   return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The problem is that after Task, objects does not appear in the suggestions and it seems that it is not available. Why?  If I run this code I get an empty template... There is entries in the database (3 rows) I have checked.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors thrown? This is wrong `{'objects', objects}` and should yield `TypeError` as the correct syntax is `{'objects': objects}`

Comment: Also may be there are no Task objects in database and `Task.objects.all()` returns empty queryset.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem since the good way of doing it is `{'objects' : objects}` and there weren't any errors shown. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in code but it doesn't make a `TypeError`... You have **created a set instead of a dictionary** to pass to the template. Django doesn't complain since it is an iterable and there is no type checking.

```
>>> {1, 2}
set([1, 2])
>>> {1: 2}
{1: 2}
```

You just have to replace the wrong line by:

```
context = Context({'objects': objects})
```

Comment: There is type checking. But I think as the querysets are lazy so django didn't tried to evaluate the queryset. If the queryset is forcefully evaluated e.g. list(queryset) then this line `context = Context({'objects', objects})` will raise `TypeError`. +1 for answer.

Comment: There is no problem with the queryset. It is constructed correctly, but once in the template, it tries to get the `objects` key from the context, which doesn't exist in a set and fail silently. But we are going deep into the error. Just remember to correctly pass a dictionary to the template context ;)